# Ошибка: Разрешение CREATE PROCEDURE запрещено в базе данных "master"

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, stored-procedures

Пытаюсь в Visual studio в Базе данных создать процедуру:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_name]
AS
    SELECT name From table1
GO
```

Но мне выдает ошибку

```
Разрешение CREATE PROCEDURE запрещено в базе данных "master".
```

Хотя я работаю с правами администратора

Не понимаю что делать, скажите пожалуйста

Comment: Тип сервера бд какой?

Comment: SQLEXPRESS вроде как, если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: **Master** это база данных SYSTEM. Не используйте ее для хранимых процедур. Вам необходимо создать собственную базу данных типа USER со своим именем. И создавайте в ней свои таблицы, хранимые процедуры и т.д.

Comment: Я создал как раз свою бд, но когда нажимаю на бд, новый запрос, то там всегда открывается поле для запроса и стоит master по умолчанию, это в visual studio